# What is the best way to handle Class/JSON/Deserilization where there are changes to how the data is serialized in C#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

The data/examples below are part of a much larger storage persisted JSON data I've only included the part that is changing.

Let's say currently I have a property and it's being serialized to storage in the following format:

Property

```
public List<string> OrgHierarchy { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

JSON

```
{
    "OrgHierarchy": [
        "Corporate",
        "Region",
        "District",
        "Store"
    ]
}
```

Now we need to make some updates to this as follows

Property

```
public List<OrgHierarchyItem> OrgHierarchy { get; set; } = new List<OrgHierarchyItem>();
```

Class

```
public class OrgHierarchyItem
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

JSON

```
{
    "OrgHierarchy": [
        {
            "Key": "Corporate",
            "Value": "My Company"
        },
        {
            "Key": "Region",
            "Value": "My Region"
        },
        {
            "Key": "District",
            "Value": "My District"
        },
        {
            "Key": "Store",
            "Value": "My Store"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I need to read in as the old and write out as the new.  While I could go and update a lot of data to make it the new format seems like there should be an easier code way to handle checking if it's the old format and deserialize it and transform it to the new format before serializing it again to storage.

I could dynamically read in the JSON and inspect the JSON that is changing and handle it that way, I could have a try/catch around the deserialize in the event that it is the old format and can't be deserialized.

I'm just looking for the best way to handle this situation as I'm sure others have had to deal with something like this.

Comment: Well, I would prefer to update the entire data then serialization wouldn't be a problem. If you insist on serializing. You could parse it into `JsonDocument` and get the `OrgHierarchy` property check the `ValueKind` if it's `ValueKind.Object` then serialize it into `List<OrgHierarchyItem>` else get the value as a string.

Comment: It might be useful to add a `version` field to your JSON data, and use the value (or lack of a value) to choose the right deserialization types?